# Filter and show results in another page

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two classes. One is Movie and other is Genre. Movie class consist of genreName as an attribute. My home page retrieves data from Genres and list them using Staggered grid view. From there,  if I select a genre, all the movies should be filtered using the genreName attribute provided in the Movie object, and all the movies in that genre should be listed in  another screen (MovieScreen). I have  provided the code below.

```
class Genre{
  final String name;
  final int totMovies;

  Genre(this.name,this.totMovies);
}

List<Genre> genres= genresData
    .map((item)=>Genre(item['name'],item['totMovies'],item['image'])).toList();

//an array
var GenresData= [
  {'name':'Horror','totMovies':17},
  {'name':'Action','totMovies':25},
  {'name':'Neo','totMovies':13},
  {'name':'Romance','totMovies':17},
];
```

```
class Movie{
  final String name;
  final int price;
  final int totLike;
  final int totRating;
  final String genreName;

  Course(this.name,this.price,this.totLike,this.totRating,this.genreName);

}

List<Movie> movies= moviesData
    .map((item)=>Movie(item['name'],item['price'],item['totLike'],item['totRating'],item['genreName'])).toList();

//an array
var moviesData= [
  {'name':'Jack reacher','price':17,'totLike':567,'totRating':4,'categoryName':'Actions'},
  {'name':'Sedious','price':34,'totLike':12,'totRating':7,'categoryName':'Horror'},
];
```

below is my staggered grid view which gets my data from genres and show.(Ignore the syntax errors)

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Course App',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: HomeScreen(),
      routes: { 
        '/movies':(context)=> MovieScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:
            Expanded(
              child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  itemCount:genres.length,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: (){
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context)=>MovieScreen(),
                              settings: RouteSettings(
                                arguments: movies[index],
                              ),
                            ));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        height:index.isEven ? 200:240,

                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              genres[index].name,
                              style: kTitleTextStyle,
                            ),Text(
                              '${genres[index].totMovies} ',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: kTextColor.withOpacity(.5),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  staggeredTileBuilder: (index)=> StaggeredTile.fit(1),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my movies screen page where the filtered movies list should show up according to the genre selected in the homescreen genres list.

```
class MovieScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Movie movie= ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:Text(movie.genreName),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20,top:50,right:20),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                itemCount:1,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    height:200,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(16),
                      color: kBlueColor,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          movie.name,
                          style: kTitleTextStyle,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Text(
                          '\$ ${movie.price}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: kTextColor
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Text(
                          '${movie.totLike} Likes'
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Text(
                            '${movie.totRating}  Ratings'
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Text(
                            '${movie.genreName} '
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
                staggeredTileBuilder: (index)=> StaggeredTile.fit(1),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I know I miss some logic in code. It would kind of any one to tell me what I am missing. and how to filter movies list using genrename and list all the movies in that specific genres. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @jan711, if you're having trouble getting your code to run, try breaking your problem down into smaller parts and solving each part on its own before bringing them together like in the code you've shown here.

Comment: What happens when you try to filter right now? Does it throw any errors? Does it Not work? Posting your full code and asking a very generic question really doesn't help...

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: There are some typo such as `genreName` and `categoryName`, `Action` and `Actions` 
Step 2: pass `genres[index].name` as arguments

```
MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => MovieScreen(),
                  settings: RouteSettings(
                    arguments: genres[index].name,
                  ),
                ));
```

Step 3: Filter and show data with `List<Movie> moviesByGenre`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String genre = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    List<Movie> moviesByGenre =
        movies.where((element) => element.genreName == genre).toList();
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

class Genre {
  final String name;
  final int totMovies;

  Genre(this.name, this.totMovies);
}

List<Genre> genres =
    GenresData.map((item) => Genre(item['name'], item['totMovies'])).toList();

//an array
var GenresData = [
  {'name': 'Horror', 'totMovies': 17},
  {'name': 'Action', 'totMovies': 25},
  {'name': 'Neo', 'totMovies': 13},
  {'name': 'Romance', 'totMovies': 17},
];

class Movie {
  final String name;
  final int price;
  final int totLike;
  final int totRating;
  final String genreName;

  Movie(this.name, this.price, this.totLike, this.totRating, this.genreName);
}

List<Movie> movies = moviesData
    .map((item) => Movie(item['name'], item['price'], item['totLike'],
        item['totRating'], item['genreName']))
    .toList();

//an array
var moviesData = [
  {
    'name': 'Jack reacher',
    'price': 17,
    'totLike': 567,
    'totRating': 4,
    'genreName': 'Action'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Jack reacher 1',
    'price': 17,
    'totLike': 567,
    'totRating': 4,
    'genreName': 'Action'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Sedious',
    'price': 34,
    'totLike': 12,
    'totRating': 7,
    'genreName': 'Horror'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Sedious 1',
    'price': 34,
    'totLike': 12,
    'totRating': 7,
    'genreName': 'Horror'
  },
];

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Course App',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: HomeScreen(),
      routes: {
        '/movies': (context) => MovieScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      itemCount: genres.length,
      crossAxisSpacing: 20,
      mainAxisSpacing: 20,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => MovieScreen(),
                  settings: RouteSettings(
                    arguments: genres[index].name,
                  ),
                ));
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            height: index.isEven ? 200 : 240,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  genres[index].name,
                  //style: kTitleTextStyle,
                ),
                Text(
                  '${genres[index].totMovies} ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(.5),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
    ));
  }
}

class MovieScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String genre = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    List<Movie> moviesByGenre =
        movies.where((element) => element.genreName == genre).toList();
    print(moviesByGenre.length);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('${genre}'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 50, right: 20),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                itemCount: moviesByGenre.length,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    height: 200,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          moviesByGenre[index].name,
                          //style: kTitleTextStyle,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '\$ ${moviesByGenre[index].price}',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Text('${moviesByGenre[index].totLike} Likes'),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Text('${moviesByGenre[index].totRating}  Ratings'),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Text('${moviesByGenre[index].genreName} '),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
                staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```